# How to read value from bean in applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I need to set a parameter value interface IP address in my applicationContext.xml

I read this setting from properties file and I use it this manner:

```
<bean id="hazelcastInterface" class="com.hazelcast.config.InterfacesConfig">
        <property name="interfaces">
            <list>
                <value>${interface.ip_address}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Now I need to get this value from a command line parameter. I use Apache Commons CLI parser, parse parameters and create my own bean commandLineConf from it and set it into ApplicationContext.

```
ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean.setInstance("commandLineConf", conf);
beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(
    "commandLineConf",
    BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(
        ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean.class)
        .getBeanDefinition());

GenericApplicationContext rootAppContext = new GenericApplicationContext(
    beanFactory);
rootAppContext.refresh();
```

But I don't know how to get value from this bean in applicationContext.xml. I have tried many way, e.g. but it doesn't work for me.

```
<bean id="hazelcastInterface" class="com.hazelcast.config.InterfacesConfig">
        <property name="interfaces">
            <list>
                <value>#{commandLineConf.ipAddress}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132231/dealing-with-command-line-arguments-and-spring ?

Comment: Yes, part of my source code is from this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your xml application context with the appropriate classes and I had the expected ipAddress from this main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        CommandLineConf conf = new CommandLineConf();
        conf.setIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
        // create root beanFactory
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

        // register bean definition for the command line
        ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean.setInstance("commandLineConf", conf);
        beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(
            "commandLineConf",
            BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(
                ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean.class)
                .getBeanDefinition());

        GenericApplicationContext rootAppContext = new GenericApplicationContext(
            beanFactory);
        rootAppContext.refresh();

        // create the application context
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { 
            "/applicationContext.xml"
        }, rootAppContext);

        InterfacesConfig hazelcastInterface = (InterfacesConfig)appContext.getBean("hazelcastInterface");
        System.out.println(hazelcastInterface.getInterfaces().get(0));

    }
```

So you are using the correct syntax to reference the address, which is: #{commandLineConf.ipAddress}

This makes me think that the problem is in the conf variable. Your code does not show how it is filled in and I doubt the ipAddress is missing. I can't be sure because you didn't include the arguments parsing in your snipplets.
Make sure that the ipAddress is present in the conf variable before you start building the spring context (i.e. by printing it).

I include the remaining classes you may need to have a working code:

- InterfacesConfig.java

  ```
  public class InterfacesConfig {
      private List<String>interfaces;
      private boolean enabled;

      public List<String> getInterfaces() {
          return interfaces;
      }

      public void setInterfaces(List<String> interfaces) {
          this.interfaces = interfaces;
      }
      public boolean isEnabled() {
          return enabled;
      }

      public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
          this.enabled = enabled;
      }

  }
  ```
- CommandLineConf.java

  ```
  public class CommandLineConf {
      private String ipAddress;
      public String getIpAddress() {
          return ipAddress;
      }

      public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
          this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
      }
  }
  ```
- ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean.java

  ```
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;

  public class ExternalBeanReferneceFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean implements BeanNameAware {

      private static Map<String, Object> instances = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      private String beanName;

      /**
       * @param instance the instance to set
       */
      public static void setInstance(String beanName, Object instance) {
          instances.put(beanName, instance);
      }

      @Override
      protected Object createInstance() 
          throws Exception {
          return instances.get(beanName);
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getObjectType() {
          return instances.get(beanName).getClass();
      }

      @Override
      public void setBeanName(String name) {
          this.beanName = name;
      }

  }
  ```
- applicationContext.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
  <bean id="hazelcastInterface" class="com.hazelcast.config.InterfacesConfig">
          <property name="interfaces">
              <list>
                  <value>#{commandLineConf.ipAddress}</value>
              </list>
          </property>
          <property name="enabled" value="true" />
      </bean>
  </beans>
  ```

Comment: No, it doesn't work... I've simplified my code to maximum, and the problem is when I trying to get the bean from `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` object. Spring throws an error that that bean doesn't exist - `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'clc' is defined
`. But the code is completely the same as yours :) I have no clue what is wrong with it.

Comment: It looks like you are referencing an undeclared bean. I need to see your applicationContext.xml to help you. Can you post it?

Comment: I am using very empty applicationContext.xml file. Thats the problem, bean I am trying to get (clc) is declared in Java code in the same way you mentioned. That is weird.

Comment: applicationContext.xml should not be empty. I included all the files I used. You should be able to make it work now.

Comment: Well, applicationContext can be empty (with "empty" I mean no beans, not empty file!), I did it because I have to minimalize side efects. But it doesn't work, the code is exactly the same as yours. I'll try it again later but I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: In your case, the applicationContext must contain at least the declaration of hazelcastInterface. Otherwise, you will not be able to inject the value of the ipAddress. I attached all the required files to my answer. You should be able to get it right if you use them.

Comment: Thanks, this morning it works - I can get a parameter value in applicationContext XML file, I have no idea why because there is no change in my code. Thanks for your effort to help me.