# Registering bean as list of Strings in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring and have a project where I am trying to inject something like the following beans:

```
ProductHandle selectedProduct
List<ProductHandle > allProducts
```

When I try to have a `List<ProductHandle>` autowired into another class, it injects a `List` containing `selectedProduct`, rather than the list I actually want. This is even though the name of the autowired property is called `allProducts`, so I thought this would identify the correct bean.

How would I go about achieving what I want?

--

Edited to show that it isn't just a case with Strings - this is a more generic and hopefully less offensive case..

--

Note beans are being registered as so, since the values are being parsed from command line args.
`mySelectedProduct` is a `ProductHandle`
`allMyProducts` is a `List<ProductHandle>`

```
try (final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
    ctx.registerBeanDefinition("selectedProducts", BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition(ProductHandle.class, "create")
        .addConstructorArgValue(mySelectedProduct)
        .getBeanDefinition());
    ctx.registerBeanDefinition("allProducts", BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition(Lists.class, "asList")
        .addConstructorArgValue(allMyProducts)
        .getBeanDefinition());
    ctx.refresh();

    final MyApp app = ctx.getBean(MyApp.class);
    app.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard data structures as Spring beans is an antipattern, don't do it. (Read here [about "stringly typed" software](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/))

Either inject the list as a `@Value`, or wrap it in a custom object that expresses the intent.

---

Regarding your updated question:

If you have a bean of type X, and register a dependency of type `List<X>`, [Spring will inject a list of all dependencies of the supplied type](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).
While this is a very handy feature, it's also one more reason never to define standard data structures (like Lists) as Spring Bean. Wrap your list in a custom object and you should be fine.

Also: `ProductHandle` sounds like it's a business object. Usually, you should not let Spring manage these, but rather the services that act on business objects. Typically, Spring would know about a `ProductRepository`, or a `ProductService`, but not a `Product` or `ProductHandle`.

The web layer is a notable exception to this rule, but even there, business objects should be method parameters, not Spring beans.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have updated the question as this issue is not unique to the `String` type so I'll remove that source of confusion. I thought `@Value` is for properties file values?

Comment: Thanks for the update. How annoying! I had hoped there was some annotation which would tell it 'stop being so clever!'. Oh well, thanks for the response. It seems like this will be the way to solve my issue, even if I don't like it! :)

Comment: What I am aiming for is the command line parameters to be parsed and validated in the main method. If valid, to be able to be used by beans. Is there a supported way to do this?

Comment: @Mark no, Spring doesn't know about command line. I'd suggest to use a CLI framework like [commons-cli](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: I think this is what I am using - to parse the command line, validate and convert to business objects. All fine. But then I wanted to use Spring & Spring Data as well. And the beans need to access those business objects. Surely this is not impossible?

Comment: Everything is possible, just not wise. beans should operate on the objects, not inject them

Comment: Ok, so it is generally not recommended to access cmd line parameters from beans? Should they just be set to static variables and accessed from there?

Comment: Maybe this should be a new question - thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Indeed, this has already been addressed to some extent here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132231/dealing-with-command-line-arguments-and-spring I was trying to follow approach 2, which is what wasn't working. While I like the `static` variables approach less (solution 1 in the above), it seems to be the way here. Ugh